# Ansible nested loops and conditional together in the same task

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
---

    - hosts: leaf-1, leaf-2
      vars_files:
        - /vars/all.yml

      tasks:
      - name: collect the vlan databse
        raw: "show vlan brief"
        register: vlan_db

      - name: compare vlan_id(.*)Ports against the vlan_db 
        set_fact:
          fact1: "{{ item.1.vlan_id }}"
          fact2: "{{ item.1.sap.inventory_hostname | join(', ') }}" 
          fact3: "{{ fact1 }}(.*){{ fact2 }}"
        failed_when: not vlan_db.stdout is regex(fact3)
        when: inventory_hostname in item.1.sap
        with_subelements:
          -  "{{ customers }}"
          -  services
```

1. I collect an output from a switch
2. I want to loop through the "customer" list and check if the "inventory_hostname" is listed in the "services.sap"

I thought I can do this with following:
`when: inventory_hostname in item.1.sap`

3. If the above check is true, I want to make a regex compare between fact3 and the stdout of the first task and raise a failure if the regex is not present in the stdout of the first task:

   `set_fact:
      fact1: "{{ item.1.vlan_id }}"
      fact2: "{{ item.1.sap.inventory_hostname | join(', ') }}"
      fact3: "{{ fact1 }}(.*){{ fact2 }}"
    failed_when: not vlan_db.stdout is regex(fact3)`

This is like nested loops and conditional together. Is there a way to do this with Ansible?
What I am doing wrong?

Just to make sure that my intention is clear:

- loop through the items in the customers list
- loop through the items in the services list in each customer
- make a check if item.1.sap has a key which matches inventory_hostname
- if the above check is true, make a comparison between the regex pattern above and the output of the first task.

/vars/all.yml looks like this:

````
    customers:
        - name: "cust-1"
          l3_vni: "101"
          services:
            - vlan_id: "10"
              vni: "1010"
              gw: "10.0.0.254/24"
              sap: 
                leaf-1: ["Eth3"]
                leaf-2: ["Eth3"]

            - vlan_id: "11"
              vni: "1011"
              gw: "10.0.1.254/24"
              sap: 
                leaf-1: ["Eth3"]
                leaf-2: ["Eth3"]

        - name: "cust-2"
          l3_vni: "102"
          services:
            - vlan_id: "20"
              vni: "1020"
              gw: "20.0.0.254/24"
              sap: 
                leaf-3: ["Eth3", "Eth4"]
                leaf-4: ["Eth3"]

            - vlan_id: "21"
              vni: "1021"
              gw: "20.0.1.254/24"
              sap: 
                leaf-3: ["Eth3"]
                leaf-4: ["Eth3"]
    ```

    a switch vlan database usually looks like this:

    ```
    leaf-1#show vlan brief

    VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
    ---- -------------------------------- --------- ----------------------
    1    default                          active    Eth5
    10   cust-1                           active    Eth3, Eth4
    20   cust-2                           active    Eth1, Eth2
    ```

error log:
````

fatal: [leaf-1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'fact1' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/vagrant/Ansible Folder Setup/NetAutHardWay/Step4-CICD/vlan_test.yml': line 23, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: compare vlan_id(.*)Ports against the vlan_db\n      ^ here\n"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

First, your playbook is syntactically invalid: it simply won't run. It will fail with the error:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>
```

This is because the content of `set_fact` should be a dictionary, not a list:

```
- name: "compare vlan_id(.*)Ports against the vlan_db"
  set_fact:
    fact1: "{{ item.1.vlan_id }}"
    fact2: "{{ item.1.sap.inventory_hostname | join(', ') }}"
    fact3: "{{ fact1 }}(.*){{ fact2 }}"
  failed_when: not vlan_db.stdout is regex(fact3)
  when: inventory_hostname in item.1.sap
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ customers }}"
    - services
```

However, you've got another problem here: your facts aren't available until *after* the `set_fact` task runs, so your conditional which is checking `is regex(fact3)` is never going to match correctly. If you want to use the value of that expression, you will need to expose the value as a variable.

But before we look at that, there's nother issue: when you write:

```
fact2: "{{ item.1.sap.inventory_hostname | join(', ') }}"
```

You are looking for a literal key named "inventory_hostname" in the `sap` dictionary. Remember, when you write `foo.bar.baz`, that's effectively shorthand for `foo["bar"]["baz"]`. You need instead:

```
fact2: "{{ item.1.sap[inventory_hostname] | join(', ') }}"
```

So, back to variables. If you want to use the value of `fact3` in your conditional, there are a couple of ways of doing that. One option is to use a `vars` block on your task, which creates new variables that exist for the duration of the task. I've used a `debug` task here to demonstrate what's happening; you could obviously replace that with a `set_fact` task if you need to persist some or all of those variables after the task completes:

```
    - name: "compare vlan_id(.*)Ports against the vlan_db"
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ fact1 }}"
          - "{{ fact2 }}"
          - "{{ fact3 }}"
      vars:
        fact1: "{{ item.1.vlan_id }}"
        fact2: "{{ item.1.sap[inventory_hostname] | join(', ') }}"
        fact3: "{{ fact1 }}(.*){{ fact2 }}"
      failed_when: not vlan_db.stdout is regex(fact3)
      when: inventory_hostname in item.1.sap
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ customers }}"
        - services
```

That is hopefully enough to point you in the right direction. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks larsks. After some struggle I was able to achieve my goal with the below play.
I had to change the failed_when syntax as well.

```
- hosts: leaf-1
  gather_facts: no 
  tags: [ verify ]
  vars_files: 
    - ../Step2-config/roles/services_config/vars/main.yml

  tasks:
    - name: collect the vlan databse
      raw: "show vlan brief"
      register: vlan_db

    - debug: 
        var: vlan_db.stdout
        var: inventory_hostname, vlan_db        

    - name: compare vlan_id(.*)Ports against the vlan_db 
      set_fact:
        fact1: "{{ item.1.vlan_id }}"
        fact2: "{{ item.0.name }}"
        fact3: "{{ item.1.sap[inventory_hostname] | join('.*')}}" 
      when: "inventory_hostname in item.1.sap"
      failed_when: not vlan_db.stdout_lines is regex(fact1 + '.*' + fact2 + '.*' + fact3)
      with_subelements:
        -  "{{ customers }}"
        -  services
```